# Sending a post request with python to extract youtube comments from json

Tags: python, ajax, youtube, python-requests, comments

I am trying a to build a comment scraper for YouTube comments. I already tried to build a scraper with selenium by opening a headless browser and scrolling down, opening comment responses and then extracting the data. But a headless browser is too slow and also the scrolling seems to be unreliable because the number of scraped comments does not match the number of comment given for each video. Maybe I did something wrong, but this is irrelevant to me right now: one of the main reasons why I would like to find another way is the time: it is too slow.

I know there have been a lot of questions about scraping youtube comment on stackoverflow, but almost every answer I found suggested to use some kind of headless browser, i.e. selenium, to do the job. I don’t like that because of the reasons mentioned above. Also, some references I found online suggest to refrain from using selenium for web scraping and instead to try reverse engineering, which means, as much as I understood, to emulate ajax calls and get the data, ideally in json.

When scrolling down a youtube video ([here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk0zUZW-U_M)), the comments are loaded dynamically. If I have a look at the XHR activity, I get a lot of information:

[image]

Looking at the XHR activity it seems like I find very information I need to make a request to get the json data with comments. But actually I struggle to construct the right the request in order to obtain the json file with the comments.

I read some tutorials online, which mostly offer simple examples which are easy to replicate. But none of them really helped me for my endeavour.

Can someone give me a hint and show me how to post the request in order to get the json file with the comments with python? I am using the requests library in Python.

I know, there is an Youtube API which can do the job, but I wanted to find out whether there is a way of doing the same thing without the API. I think it should be possible.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? Let me know.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. I thought no one would answer. Yes, I am still struggling. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: So here is the full code that you're looking for to achieve those results. If you have any questions, let me know (either on here or in the git issues. I'm d0tN3t). Again, it works and you can also study the code on how and what it is doing. https://github.com/egbertbouman/youtube-comment-downloader

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had found this one before and I am trying to do exactly the same, but somehow I always get an empty string from the post request. I could just copy paste the code, I know, but I wanted to understand what I am doing wrong. I think I have to spend some more time on that and maybe I will find a solution. I am sure I am just missing something. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so depending on when you came across that git repo could be the reason why you're running into some issues. There's an old and new API. The screenshot you posted is from the new API. Which the original owner of the repo updated in February. Both APIs are in the downloader.py script. Give it another look, copy and paste portions of it for you to understand what is going on. 

Thats what I did in my own version when I realized there were 2 APIs and thought that git repo was dead. (https://github.com/egbertbouman/youtube-comment-downloader/issues/13#issuecomment-583930787)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try it.